# Kendo window - Window does not open up on clicking the button for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have bug in my ui. I have a button to open up the Kendo Window when it is clicked. When I click the button for the first time open the window does get open. When I close the window and click the button again to open up the window, the window does not open.

The problem is that I even don't see any error in the console too.

I have created a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rhjhbhy3/) of my code and providing the code snippet below:

```
$("#open1").click(function() {
    $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "500px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Window 1"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your jsfiddle code and now it is working. Here is the updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/rhjhbhy3/3/)

Below is the actual way how the `Kendo window` widget should be initialized and how to open the window on a button click.

**Please note that in the DEMO I have just modified the code for `$("#win1")` and your code for `$("#win2")` still needs the modification as per the below code.**

Below is the code snippet from the DEMO:

```
var win1 = $("#win1");
win1.kendoWindow({
    visible: false,//this attribute initially hides the window
    width: "300px",
    height: "500px",
    modal: true,
    title: "Window 1"
});
$("#open1").click(function() {
    win1.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
});
```

Comment: Hey can you let me know what you did so that in future I can do it by myself

Comment: I have modified that way you initialize the window object and how you handle the reopening of the window.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you think I have resolved your query :)

Comment: Have you tried my solution yet ? Let me know if you have any issues with it or else you may accept and up vote my answer :)